# Fit in with or to

Tags: prepositions, difference

There is a question but I still cannot understand it. Here it is:

> Your personality type not only predicts how well your skills will match the demands of the work tasks in a particular job, it also predicts how well you will fit in ____ the culture of the work site as shaped by the people who will surround you.

> A) about
> B) by
> C) to
> D) with
> E) without

I thought it was C/to but the answer is D/with.

I do appreciate the explanation because I struggle to understand why it is not C.

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, we use "fit in **to**" to describe *physically* fitting into something, and "fit in **with**" to describe being a good match to other things.

[Macmillan describes it this way](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fit-in-with):

> (fit in with something) to be correct, appropriate, or sensible in relation to something else

Comment: In Britain I would suggest that in this example either "to" or "with" would fit equally. But your rule seems to me a good one. Something fits in "to" the wider picture, but you fit in well "with" your work colleagues.

Comment: For physical fitting, wouldn't you usually use "fit into" rather than "fit in to"? I think "fit in to" is just a nonstandard substitute for "fit in with."

Comment: @alphabet  I agree that I would usually use "fit into" rather than "fit in to".  I don't think that they're really substitutable, though - consider "I fit in with my colleagues" vs "I fit into my colleagues"!

Comment: @stangdon My point is: "fit into" is used for physically fitting into something. "Fit in with" describes being a good match. "Fit in to" (three words) can mean either; it's nonstandard, likely resulting from conflating "fit into" and "fit in with."

Answer (score 0):

"Fit in with" is a very commonly used expression in English, almost a fixed phrase. "Fit in to" is not **wrong**. It could be used here. But "with" is so commonly used in this sort of construction that anything else would feel a bit odd.